# MacBook 2014 thunderbolt 2

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I was wondering if there any use of thunderbolt 2 ports in MacBook Pro nowadays. There are hubs and docks for thunderbolt 3, not for thunderbolt 2. And  2014-2015 macbook pros have 2 thunderbolts... are they good for anything other than connecting an external display to them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is use for Thunderbolt 2. Recall that Thunderbolt 2 supports throughput of 20Gps, which is 40x faster than the USB2 on your Macbook. USB3 can do similar, but in most cases does not. So, if you need to transfer many gb of files, photos, or do a backup, Thunderbolt is the way. In addition, Thunderbolt can support your monitor, Ethernet and USB over the one single connection (such as using a thunderbolt dock).

Even better, Apple makes a Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter, so it can work with the Thunderbolt 3 docks and devices:

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter

Comment: The OP's Mac has USB 3 (5 Gb/s) ports.

Comment: It's likely that the halved bandwidth may cause some issues with some TB3 hubs.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find TB2 devices and adapters now, but there were [USB adapters, Ethernet adapters and hubs](https://www.macworld.com/article/222636/what-you-need-to-know-about-thunderbolt-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find things on eBay like RAID enclosures for TB2, at a cheap price secondhand. You may need to replace the drives at some point, but that's what RAID is all about.

The old Apple Thunderbolt Display is tailor-made for the TB2 port, and is probably a lot cheaper now the new Studio Display is out. That is a glorified TB hub, with Ethernet, FireWire and USB2 ports.

Apple did make a TB2-to-Ethernet adaptor, which might still be useful, if you can find one.

A TB2 cable is also the fastest way to connect two Macs of that vintage together, if you need to copy files between them.

I certainly wouldn't invest too heavily in TB2 gear, though, depending on how many more years you think you're going to get out of your 2014 Mac.